# javascript does not read a nested JSON array correctly

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am using Node js to process a JSON object
The Json structure is like:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "datadetails":{  
         "first":"abc",
         "second":"1920",
         "coordinates":[  
            {  
               "X":0,
               "Y":3,
               "exists":true
            },
            {  
               "X":23,
               "Y":35,
               "exists":true
            },
            {  
               "X":42,
               "Y":16,
               "exists":true
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

when I try to get the data in html I can until I try to use the coordinates array

I am using {{data.datadetails.second}} to get each field

But when I use {{data.datadetails.coordinates[0].X}} it shows blank space

When in javascript I try to use the whole array it gives me [object Object], [object Object]... as the result... just a string of "object" words

How can I have the real contents from my nested array?

Comment: `{{...}}` isn't JavaScript. Are you using some sort of template engine?

Comment: I am using mustache to "combine" the data from the json object inside the html, so it is {{data.datadetail.second}} for example to get the value, but when trying to get values from the nested array it just does not work

Comment: if you have that json, maybe you may do `const json = JSON.parse(yourJson)`. Then, you can do:

`json.data.datadetails.coordinates[0].X` to get the proper value for the first X coordinate.

Comment: yes I did that to... trying to parse the whole object or just part of it... the result is "undefined"...

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct notation to access a particular array index in Mustache:

```
{{data.datadetails.coordinates.0.X}}
```

If you want to iterate over the array, use `{{#...}}`:

```
{{#data.datadetails.coordinates}}
  X: {{X}}
  Y: {{Y}}
{{/data.datadetails.coordinates}}
```

Comment: hi, thanks! that works for one specific item of the array directly in the html, but what about using the whole array? The array size can be different and I need the whole to "draw" the coordinates... any suggestion? I need to use it inside an embeded javascript...

Comment: mmm well... this is the result... when I send to print in the console...

  X
  :
   
  0
  ,
  Y
  :
   
  5
  0
2  2
  .
2  8
  4
  X
  :
   
  8
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
. as you can see... it "converts" the numbers in individual characters... not even words...

Comment: Sounds like that might be an issue in your template, hard to tell without seeing it.

Comment: the template is ok... there it works perfect... the problem happens when I try to use the array in a variable inside an embeded script in the html like doing "var data = '{{data.datadetails.coordinates}}';"' .... the rest of variables work ok but the array...

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question to explain what _exactly_ it is that you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way, thanks @robertklep you guided me...

```
    var data = [];
    "{{#data.datadetails.coordinates}}";
            var coord = {
                X:Number("{{X}}"),
                Y:Number("{{Y}}")
            };
         data.push(coord);
    "{{/data.datadetails.coordinates}}";
```

and it is a json array...